# Can't write directive in svc file

Tags: iis, rest

It could be a dumb question but I need the solution.

I would like to deploy my first REST web service in IIS by following this step : [How to Host a Restful WCF Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747751/how-to-host-a-restful-wcf-web-service)

But I have a problem : I don't know how to write the directive in the svc file.
There are 3 files :

- IService1.cs
- Service1.svc
- Service1.svc.cs

I double clicked the Service1.svc but I always get Service1.svc.cs

I can't find "View Designer" icon as I found in webform file.

I build the project using Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Would you please tell me what mistakes I did?

Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the svc file and select "View markup"

Comment: Sometimes all you need is just another pair of eyes!